# Invalid conversion from char to const char when using Insert function from <string>

Tags: c++, string, stdvector

OK, I'm trying to work on a monolith of a program, and I've got a decent amount of the errors sorted through.  The one's that's mystifying me right now is when I got "invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char'" for this line:

```
sequenceMutation.insert( initialPosition, 'T' );
```

`initialPosition` itself is meant to be equal to `sequenceIleChains[0] + 3`, which corresponds to the index of the last character for the first Isoleucine group (plus one to account for the behavior of `insert`).  I don't know why it would be outputting this, considering I initialize and declare `string sequenceMutation` locally in the function without `const`, so if anyone can figure this out, it would be useful.

Additionally, if it may help, I used

```
string sequenceMutation = sequenceOld[sequence];
```

to initialize and declare `sequenceMutation`, where `sequenceOld` is a vector that I pass by reference using `vector<string>& sequenceOld` and sequence is a integer value I initialize, declare, pass from the for loop in `int main()` that I'm putting this function within.

Comment: What's the type of `initialPosition`? From the sounds of it, it is an some integral value. If so, there is no overload of `insert()` in `std::basic_string` which takes an integer and a `char`. Maybe you meant `sequenceMutation.insert(initialPosition, 1, 'T')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `'` by `"`, you are inserting a string, not a char, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/

Comment: Thanks you are a lifesaver.  However, why am I getting an issue converting from `char` to `int` when I declare this function

`void printMutation( const vector<string>&, const vector< vector<int> >&, int, ofstream& );`

Comment: Where are you getting the error? When you call the function? Please post the code and the types of the variables, as one cannot figure out what's going on just by looking at the function prototype.

Comment: OK, I've put the entirety of the program in a coderpad here: https://coderpad.io/720710 .  Each file I'm writing is bordered by a start and end comment, and I added the compiler's error text at the bottom, with a comment denoting the line position in the coderpad analog to the line for the function.

Comment: `index` doesn't seem to be defined in `main()`, so at line 254 your are invoking the function without knowing what `index` is.

Comment: You rock, man, and after noticing another thing, it cmpiled.  Let's just hope for no segmentation faults.

Comment: Yeah... this sucks. You cannot really see the line where the fault happens, since it is undefined behaviour (the fault can happen at any time basically). For example, if you access an array out of bounds, the program may run, but sometimes may crash. Best thing is to try to debug it step by step and see what's happening, and check for memory allocations in your code, or for accessing a `std::vector` out of bounds (can replace the `[]` operator with `at()` operator, the latter will check for out of bounds and will throw an exception that you can make sense of)

Comment: Well, I figured out the first seg fault, as I didn't give the vector any size to work with.  Now, though, it's stopping me here: `sequenceMutation[ index + 1 ] = sequenceMutation[ index ];`.  `sequenceMutation` is a string, and I need to shift characters to the left.  However, the previous function, which shifted characters to the right, didn't segment.  So is there something I didn't do?

Oh, just to note, this is from the function mutationTwo if you're still using the coderpad for reference.  

EDIT: it seems printing index leaves me with a value of '44699'.  What is that exactly?

Comment: Probably in `[index+1]` you are reaching out of bounds, i.e. when `index=sequenceMutation.size()` you will get an out of bound access. You can use `std::rotate` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate and take care of the last character (which will be the head of the original vector). And your current code is rotating to the right actually, i.e. the elements are right-shifted. Actually your code doesn't shift, because you end up overwriting elements, take a simple case of a vector {1,2,3,4} and see what's going on.